# Where in the vue code base is it creating the vue.esm.browser.js file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, rollupjs

I am looking at vue and trying to figure out how they build the vue.esm.browser.js file. Everything else seems to be in ./script/config.js but I can't find anything in there about esm in the browser. Is it using a dependency or something to generate the file?

I also noticed that it isn't listed in the output files when rollup runs.

So my question is, where in the [Vue code base](https://github.com/vuejs/vue) is it creating the esm.browser file?

Comment: Well that explains a bit it looks like if I blow away the dist file and rebuild it isn't there so how do I generate it after the fact?

Comment: Looking at `package.json` it seems like it's created using the `dev:esm` script.

Comment: Nope that is absolutely not it that creates vue.runtime.esm.js not vue.esm.browser.js... rollup -w -c scripts/config.js --environment TARGET:web-runtime-esm

Comment: The two files are https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js and https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.esm.browser.js Notice that the runtime one still contains refs to process.env