# How do I get vue-router working with esm in browser

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to get vue-router to work with esm in the browser but when I import the vue-router.esm.js file I get

```
vue:573 [Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "ReferenceError: process is not defined"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue:573
logError @ vue:1727
globalHandleError @ vue:1722
handleError @ vue:1711
callHook @ vue:2896
Vue._init @ vue:4528
Vue$3 @ vue:4627
(anonymous) @ main.js:24

vue:1731 ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at VueRouter.init (vue-router.esm.js:2394)
    at Vue$3.beforeCreate (vue-router.esm.js:527)
    at callHook (vue:2894)
    at Vue$3.Vue._init (vue:4528)
    at new Vue$3 (vue:4627)
    at main.js:24
```

How do I get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I removed all conditionals that required `process.env` and I am no longer receiving an error. However, this is a super hacky solution as I have to maintain a local copy and deal with updates manually. I tried looking into how Vue does this in the core project but haven't gotten a response yet.

[Where in the vue code base is it creating the vue.esm.browser.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983434/where-in-the-vue-code-base-is-it-creating-the-vue-esm-browser-js-file)